# CSS Grid items overflow wrapper

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Can someone please explain me why the usage of grid-gap in the wrapper overflows the items? The manual just says it ADDS space between the items, not extending them in any way or something.

*CODEPEN:* [Source](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eavgvW)

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.header {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  background: red
}

.footer {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  background: green
}

.item {
  padding: 10px
}

.content {
  height: 180px
}

.image {
  background: yellow
}

.desc {
  background: blue
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .content {
    grid-column: 1/3
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item header">Header</div>
  <div class="item content image">Image</div>
  <div class="item content desc">Description</div>
  <div class="item content image">Image</div>
  <div class="item content desc">Description</div>
  <div class="item footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As a simple fix you could use just `grid-row-gap` instead; but I'd imagine the cause for the behavior is that the grid is still trying to keep the items a certain size (50%), not really sure though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason is in fact that you are setting the columns to use 50% of the width of the parent, which also includes the gaps. For CSS Grid it would be best to use `fr` units to specify equal width columns.

In your case, if you use `1fr 1fr` or `repeat(2, 1fr)` instead of `50% 50%`, you actually tell the grid to set its columns to 1 fraction of the *available space*, this will take the gaps into account and not overflow the parent.

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.header {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  background: red
}

.footer {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  background: green
}

.item {
  padding: 10px
}

.content {
  height: 180px
}

.image {
  background: yellow
}

.desc {
  background: blue
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .content {
    grid-column: 1/3
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="item header">Header</div>

  <div class="item content image">Image</div>
  <div class="item content desc">Description</div>

  <div class="item content image">Image</div>
  <div class="item content desc">Description</div>

  <div class="item footer">Footer</div>

</div>
```